# SQL Server - How to restore the database except specific tables

Tags: sql-server, restore, ssis

Can someone provide your insights, what is best option to restore the database from SQL Server (say prod to integration). I want to exclude specific tables during restore.

1. Using Script
2. Using SSIS
3. Using 3rd Party Tools.

If am using SSIS Integration Instance, does it involve licensing cost ? Some thoughts on this would help.

Comment: You can add DROP TABLE code to your process that does the restore, before setting back to Multi_user.   Of course, you will have to account for objects that reference those tables, such as foreign keys, dependent SPs, etc.  Is this due to size, or just not wanting certain data visible in lower environments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To exclude certain tables from your refresh of the integration environment, with a backup from production, you will need to make use of a staging\data cleansing environment.

The plan would be:

1. Backup production
2. Restore backup in staging
3. Drop the unwanted tables
4. Backup staging
5. Restore backup in integration

This plan could easily be implemented with PowerShell ([DBATools](https://dbatools.io/) is well worth a look) or SSIS.

If you like coding, go for PowerShell. If you like dragging icons around the screen, go for SSIS. Both can get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Your otpions are as @Sivalingaamorthy outlined. 
However I would like to share my experience.
I have configured daily tasks using Agent jobs and t-sql scripts of my own to restore backups of prod databases to Testing environment where I test backups for errors.
TO restore backups using SSIS you will probably need some kind of tsql scripts for you specific environment.
Also you migh find helpful this tool from ApexSQL:
http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_restore.aspx